# How come I can't move the contents of my .htaccess file into my virtual host?

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I have an .htaccess file for my Wordpress website with this content.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I moved this content into the Apache virtual host for my site (below) and deleted the htaccess file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 68.183.153.223
DocumentRoot /home/david/wordpressWebSite

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I attempt to restart Apache, Apache outputs an error.

```
RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files
Action 'restart' failed.
```

I thought that htaccess file contents could be moved to virtual hosts. What is awry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), `RewriteBase` "Sets the base URL for per-directory rewrites".

Since you're not setting up per-directory rewrites, the directive is meaningless outside of an .htaccess file for a particular directory.

Comment: Thanks, but weird things happen if I remove RewriteBase. In other words, the content of the site loads, but Apache treats links to my CSS as a page in Wordpress as opposed to a static file. In fact, the URL for my CSS redirects to "/wp-content/themes/myTheme/style.css/" with a "/" at the end.

Comment: What's the actual URL for the stylesheet? I suspect this is caused by how `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` gets treated differently in .htaccess context, although I'm not sure I see where the trailing slash would be added.

Comment: Ah, I solved the problem after removing RewriteBase. I found the solution here (http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2005/12/18/whats-up-with-request_filename-in-mod_rewrite/). `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is relative to the document root. Without RewriteBase as in an htaccess file, I have to resort to `RewriteCond /home/david/wordpressWebSite%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Otherwise, the rewrite will always occur. Nonetheless, I do not like this solution since I am repeating "/home/david/wordpressWebSite" twice in my virtual host, which is against DRY. Do you know how I can just mention it once?

Comment: Using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! `%{REQUEST_URI}` did the trick. I guess it should be noted to future viewers of this question though that REQUEST_URI does have a performance drawback due to an extra internal subrequest. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 2):

RewriteBase does not work in virtualhost files.

The question you probably want to ask is:

> How do I include relative paths in VHost RewriteRules?

Particularly, in vhosts, *_FILENAME returns a slash followed by the REQUEST_URI, instead of being relative or mapped to the filesystem!
Eg, %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}

- In .htaccess: "assets/style.css"
- In a vhost file: "/assets/style.css"
- You need: "/var/www/assets/style.css"

There are several solutions:

- [Solution #1](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteContext): %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}

  ```
  RewriteRule ^/foo/bar$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/baz

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule (.*) /script.cgi
  ```
- [Solution #2](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2005/12/18/whats-up-with-request_filename-in-mod_rewrite/): `<Directory> tags`

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  <Directory "/var/www/">
      ...
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule (.*) /script.cgi
  </Directory>
  ```

  > Within the directory tag, *_FILENAME is treated the same as in a htaccess file.
  >   There may be an issue using this when the server has multiple aliases.
- [Solution #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836359/how-come-i-cant-move-the-contents-of-my-htaccess-file-into-my-virtual-host#comment14109940_10836419): %{REQUEST_URI}

  > Use %{*_URI} instead of %{*_FILENAME} where possible
  >   Not a real answer. Just pointing out that *_URI's won't have to be rewritten as they are not supposed to map to the filesystem, and therefore vhost/htaccess paths are the same. However, it is not always possible to use REQUEST_URI, and David Faux commented above that it is slower. Besides, thi